# p:treeTable children root nodes duplicated after update

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, treetable

I'm getting a weird behavior when I try to update a `h:panelGroup` with a `p:treeTable` from a `p:tree` ajax event.

I have a `p:tree` element updating a form based on `ui:include` fragments. On the first load, everything works fine, but, when I select a tree, the ajax event is fired, the `p:treeTable` is updated but the nodes are duplicated.

My tree is this, the select listener event (`onNodeSelect`) builds a `p:treeNode` variable, and update a flag to show the `p:treeTable` page:

```
<p:tree value="#{mbArquitectura.raiz}" style="border: none;"
        dynamic="true" 
        selectionMode="single" 
        cache="false"
        selection="#{mbArquitectura.selectedNode}" 
        var="node" 
        id="tree">

    <p:ajax onstart="muestraLoader(); cleanPriceTreeTable();"
            oncomplete="ocultaLoader(); removeDuplicatedIds();"
            event="select" 
            listener="#{mbArquitectura.onNodeSelect}"
            global="true"
            update=":frmPromocion :frmPromocion:ttPrecio :panelDialogos" />

    <p:ajax onstart="muestraLoader();" oncomplete="ocultaLoader();"
            event="expand" 
            listener="#{mbArquitectura.nodeExpand}"
            global="true"
            update=":frmPromocion :frmPromocion:ttPrecio :panelDialogos" />

    <p:ajax onstart="muestraLoader();" oncomplete="ocultaLoader();"
            event="collapse" 
            listener="#{mbArquitectura.nodeCollapse}"
            global="true"
            update=":frmPromocion :frmPromocion:ttPrecio :panelDialogos" />

    <p:treeNode id="treeNode">
        <b>
            <h:outputText value="#{node}" id="lblNode" style="color: #{node.label}" />
        </b>
    </p:treeNode>
</p:tree>
```

My updated form (`:frmPromocion`) is this:

```
<ui:define name="content" id="content">
    <h:form id="frmPromocion" style="font-size: x-small">
        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{mbArquitectura.agregarPromocion}">
            <ui:include src="/pages/ArqSeven/ArqPromocion.xhtml" />
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{mbArquitectura.precio}">
            <ui:include src="/pages/ArqSeven/ArqPrecio.xhtml" />
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:form>
```

Inside the file `ArqPecio.xhtml`, there is the following dataTable:

```
<p:treeTable id="ttPrecio" 
             liveResize="true"
             value="${mbArquitectura.raizPrecio}" 
             var="item" 
             style="width: 1200px;" 
             styleClass="grid-content">

    <p:ajax event="expand" listener="#{mbArquitectura.priceExpand}" update=":frmPromocion:ttPrecio" />
    <p:ajax event="collapse" listener="#{mbArquitectura.priceCollapse}" update=":frmPromocion:ttPrecio" />
    <p:ajax event="select" listener="#{mbArquitectura.priceSelect}" update=":frmPromocion:ttPrecio" />
    <p:ajax event="unselect" listener="#{mbArquitectura.priceUnselect}" update=":frmPromocion:ttPrecio" />
</p:treetable>
```

As I said, the inicial load works fine:

[image: first load]

But, when I select a node from the tree, the `p:treeTable` nodes are duplicated, like this:

[image: duplicated nodes]

How can I fix this behaviour?

Comment: Hello,
I think that there is an update problem. I hope this solves your problem.

Please change `update=":frmPromocion :frmPromocion:ttPrecio :panelDialogos"` with `update=":frmPromocion :panelDialogos" ` and try again.

Thanks.

Comment: please read [ask] and [mcve] amd improve your question

Comment: @mns45 Hi,  thanks for your time,  i try your advice but the behavior is the same :( do you have an other tip? Thanks.